# How do I invoke a Squeak method when given the method name as a string?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How do I invoke a Squeak method when given the method name as a string? 
is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
perform: aSymbol
perform: aSymbol with: anObject
perform: aSymbol withArguments: anArrayOfArguments
```

Where aSymbol is your method selector.
For example instead of `1 + 2` your could write:

```
1 perform: #+ with: 2
```

If your method selector is stored as a `String`, you have to convert it to a `Symbol` first:

```
1 perform: '+' asSymbol with: 2

5 perform: 'raisedTo:modulo:' asSymbol withArguments: #(2 3)
```

Comment: My string contains a name not one character so it wont help me to convert to a symbol..thanx anyway

Comment: @Shiran I've added 1 more example in the end. Take a look if it makes sense. Otherwise I don't understand your comment about _"contains a name not one character"_

Comment: @Shiran In Smalltalk a `Symbol` is a unique `String`, not to be confused with a `Character`. *Unique String* means: `'a String' asSymbol == 'a String' asSymbol`.